# I get syntax error while setting the state

Tags: reactjs, next.js, frontend, blockchain, ethers.js

I am trying to set the initial state in Next.js like this:

```js
constructor(props: Props) {
    super(props);
    const emptyContract = new ethers.Contract(
      "",
      "",
      new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider("")
    );
    this.state = {
      account: "0x0",
      blockchainDataLoaded: false,
      futNFT: emptyContract,
      futNFTMatch: emptyContract,
      futNFTTraining: emptyContract,
      futNFTTransfer: emptyContract,
      vrfConsumer: emptyContract,
    };
  }
```

But I get this error: `SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the second parameter of the Contract constructor is an array so replace:

```
const emptyContract = new ethers.Contract(
  "",
  "",
  new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider("")
);
```

with:

```
const emptyContract = new ethers.Contract(
  "",
  [],
  new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider("")
);
```